# Check if file name exist in file

Tags: powershell

Lets say i have 8 files in a folder, and I have a file.csv with 5 lines.
The 8 files start with the same like in the file.csv 0022***_something.csv.  So I want to check if filename exist in file.csv

> file.csv lines look like:
>
> 0022150;something;something;something
>       0022151;something;something;something
>       0022152;something;something;something
>       0022153;something;something;something
>       0022154;something;something;something

```
    $FileCsv = Get-Content "\\sharedFolder\file.csv" | foreach {($_ -split ";")[0..0]} | Where {($_ -like "00*")}
    $FolderPath = "\\SharedFolder\Path\"
    Foreach ($file in $folderPath)
    {
         $file = $file.Substring(0,7)
         if ($file exist in $FileCsv) #Not sure how I get this line right.
    {
         $file + "Exist"
    }
    else
    {
         $file + "Does not exist"
    }
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at [Test-Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path?view=powershell-5.1). You should read the complete help including the examples, please. You might search for similar examples here in SO or in the internet in general as well ... there are literally thousands of them. ;-)

Comment: I have already check that one, but I dont know how to make it foreach file, to check if it's in a csv file.

Comment: So you should make a step back and take your time to learn the basics of Powershell first. another tip: If you have a CSV file you should use [Import-CSV](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-5.1) instead of Get-Content. You should use the advantages of native Powershell cmdlets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
$FolderPath = "\\SharedFolder\Path\"  #"# This is where the files are found

# read the CSV file, using a header 'Name' for the first column and get this column as an array of strings.
$NamesInCsv = (Import-Csv -Path "\\SharedFolder\file.csv" -Header Name -Delimiter ';').Name

# get a list if files with names that start with '022'
Get-ChildItem -Path $FolderPath -Filter '022*' -File | ForEach-Object {
    # if the first 7 characters of the name are in the names from the CSV
    if ($_.Name.Length -ge 7 -and $NamesInCsv -contains $_.Name.Substring(0,7)) {
        Write-Host "File $($_.Name) exists in the Csv"
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "File $($_.Name) does not exist in the Csv"
    }
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks alot, have looking for this for weeks :-) 
Works great.